# Understanding Async Javascript code

Tags: javascript, node.js

Recently, I have started learning Node.js with [Nodeschool](http://nodeschool.io) exercises. But I have problem with understanding solution for this problem:

```
Your program will get some html written to stdin. Convert all the inner html to
upper-case for elements with a class name of "loud".
```

Official solution is:

```
var trumpet = require('trumpet');
var through = require('through');

var tr = trumpet();

var loud = tr.select('.loud').createStream();

loud.pipe(through(function(buf){
    this.queue(buf.toString().toUpperCase());
})).pipe(loud);

process.stdin.pipe(tr).pipe(process.stdout);
```

What I can not understand is this part:

```
process.stdin.pipe(tr).pipe(process.stdout);
```

This code does not use **loud** variable to output solution. Can anyone explain me this magic code?

P.S: I come to Node.js from PHP, and have problems with understanding Async Javascript.

Comment: You should probably read the documentation for `trumpet` which can be [found here](https://github.com/substack/node-trumpet), since that seems to be the module that you don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar confusion, and [this discussion](https://github.com/nodeschool/discussions/issues/346) helped me out.

---

I think you might be confusing the two streams `loud` and `tr`.

`tr` is the main trumpet stream

- It is a transform stream (has input and output like a pipe)
- It takes html as input
- It outputs html
- we connect `stdin` to its input, and we connect its output to `stdout`

`loud` is another stream, we created `loud` by asking `tr` to select html elements with class `loud`

- It is a duplex stream (has input and output like a telephone)
- it outputs or sends html elements
- it also receives html elements

`tr` behaves such that, when html is streamed to it, if there are elements with class `loud`, they are output from loud, which sends them to the `through` stream you built for making the text uppercase, which sends them to back to `loud`'s input, where they are reinserted into the html `tr` originally received and output from `tr`.

I guess an important thing to note is that, although `loud` has an important connection with `tr`, they are not actually piped together at all.

---

While `tr` and `loud` are absolutely connected, the connection is not that clear, and it does not relate to the pipes we see here.

You do want to send your html back to `tr`, but we achieve that by sending it back to `loud`. Anything sent to the input part of `tr` is interpreted as new html to be processed, so we can't send to the input of `tr`. Instead we send to the input of `loud`, which through some magic internal to trumpet, causes it to be output from `tr`.

It might help to think of the flows separately:

- `stdin` > `tr` (which does some kind of processing) > `stdout`
- `loud` > `through` > `loud`

So, while both `tr` and `loud` are duplex streams, meaning they have both an input and an output, they act in very different ways.

`tr` receives an input, and then sends output as a result.

`loud` sends an output, and waits for input to arrive as a result.

If you like, you can imagine `loud` as two streams, one read and one write, instead of just one read/write stream. This makes it look a lot more like `stdin` and `stdout`.

`loudout` > `through` > `loudin`

`loud` absolutely does know that when it receives input it should pass it back to tr, this just happens to be internal to trumpet, making it a bit mysterious